# What is the cardinality of an infinite product of sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We have $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ a family of sets. We can suppose that the axiom of choice is true. I am trying to prove that for every $\kappa$ infinite cardinal, we have $card(\prod_{i \in I} A_i)<\kappa'$ for a certain $\kappa '$ cardinal (to be determined) if and only if $\forall i\in I,card(A_i)<\kappa$ and $card(I)<\kappa$. How can one prove this ? Is this even true ?

Comment: Canonically, one can show that $\kappa^\kappa = 2^\kappa=\mathscr{P}(\kappa)$, for cardinals $\kappa$, which might be enough for what you're after - $2^\kappa\leq\kappa^\kappa\leq\left(2^\kappa\right)^\kappa = 2^{\kappa\ \times\ \kappa} = 2^\kappa$.

Answer (score -1):

The cardinality of the product of a family of sets is easily proved to be the $\sup$ of the cardinalities of the sets in the family (provided they are infinite of course) or the cardinality of $I$, whatever is bigger.

If $\kappa$ is a regular cardinal, then you can set $\kappa' = \kappa$, because by definition no sequence of less than $\kappa$ cardinals all smaller that $\kappa$ can sum $\kappa$.

If on the other side $\kappa$ is singular (that is, its cofinality is strictly less than $\kappa$) then you can have that $\sup(card(A_i)) = \kappa$ if $I$ is the cofinality of $\kappa$. so you can set $\kappa'$ to be the successor of $\kappa$.

I'll leave you to fill out the details.

**Edit:**

Thinking a bit more, it seems that I am completely wrong!

One of the reasons is that (provided enough $A_i$ are at least $2$) then

$$
\left| \prod_{i\in I} A_i\right| ≥ \left| \mathscr{P}(I) \right|
$$

and that number may be anything...

Comment: I see that $sup(card(I),sup_{i \in I}(card(A_i)) \leq card(\prod_{i \in I}A_i)$, but I do not manage to see an injection in the other direction.

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I was completely wrong. Big time wrong. The cardinality of $\prod A_i$ dominates in general the power set of $I$ itself. And of course we have no idea about its cardinality.....